# Migrate communities from sandbox to production

Tags: migration, community

Is there any document /steps to migrate communities created in sandbox to production.

Or do we cannot migrate.we have to create a fresh one in production? and update login templates etc if necessary?

Answer (score 3):

If you use Eclipse, it's possible to query your sandbox and get the basic configuration of your Community and keep it with the rest of your metadata, and hence be deployed to other environments with the Force.com Migration Tool.

Having said that, I've found that the Community has to be created on each new environment prior to deploying the Community metadata to that environment.

Comment: Hi Beamso, is anything changed over the years? Did you recently come across any other things to be noted on deploying Communities using the Migration Tool?